# TortoiseSvn - Automatically update multiple external properties

Tags: batch-file, svn, tortoisesvn, revision, externals

I'm currently working on tortoise svn. In order to be able to automatically tag trunk projects so i need to focus on the external properties. As well i would like to edit them automatically using a batch file.

Until now what i've done is:

- Getting the last version of the folder which is pointed by the
  external property (in order to be able to tag a specific version and
  not the head one)
- Edit the external property using command line

My batch file looks like this :

```
::GETTING THE LAST VERSION NUMBER OF THE SOURCE DIRECTORY
svnversion -c %SRC_PATH_WC% | sed -e 's/[MS]//g' -e 's/^[[:digit:]]*://'>temp.txt
set /p VERSION=<temp.txt
del temp.txt
echo %VERSION%

pause
::CREATING THE SVN:EXTERNAL WITH THE VERSION CHOOSEN
svn propset svn:externals "%DIRECTORY_NAME% -r%VERSION% %SVN_SRC_PATH%" . 
pause
```

Now I would like to be able to set multiple external properties. I think i can't by using the svn propset command but i have no clue on what other command to use and how to use it.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: `svnversion -c` have to output clean digit. I can't understand your piping

Comment: My method on getting the number of the last version works.My problem isn't here but on the objectif of creating and editing multiple svn:externals properties with command line

Comment: Just collect all definitions in one place and process externals line-by-line

Answer (score 0):

I've found my answer on another site.

Here is what i've used :

```
::CREATE FILE AND WRITE THE SVN:EXTERNALS PROPERTIES
echo %DIRECTORY_NAME1% -r%VERSION1% %SVN_SRC_PATH1% > svn_externals
echo %DIRECTORY_NAME2% -r%VERSION2% %SVN_SRC_PATH2% >> svn_externals

::CREATING THE SVN:EXTERNAL WITH THE VERSION CHOOSEN
svn propset svn:externals -F svn_externals .
```